# Module 'rest_framework.request' has no attribute 'method' Django error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm having a strange error and I didn't find answers nowhere and that's mean that I need your help(again).

So, I'm having two views in my views.py file and I'm trying to adding GET and POST methods for one view, I've tried to check the method with request. Method but rest frame work module tells me that has no that attribute, can you help me, please, with a fix for this issue?
Thank you!

In models.py I have:

```
class ChatViewSet(ConversationViewSet):

    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def get_chat(self, **kwargs):

        if request.method == 'GET':
            information = Chat.objects.all()
            tutorials_serializer = ChatSerializer(information, many=True).data
            return JsonResponse(tutorials_serializer, safe=False)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            tutorial_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            tutorial_serializer = ChatSerializer(data=tutorial_data)
            tutorial_data['status'] = 'new'
            tutorial_data['chat_id'] += 1
            if tutorial_serializer.is_valid():
                tutorial_serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(tutorial_serializer.data,
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return JsonResponse(tutorial_serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^conversation/', ConversationViewSet.get_all),
    url(r'^conversation/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', ConversationViewSet.get_by_id),
    url(r'chat', ChatViewSet.get_chat),
]
```

And error:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.request' has no attribute 'method'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is inside a *class* which I assume from the name is a `ViewSet` that means you really don't need that `api_view` decorator. The `api_view` decorator is used to make an api view from a functional view and not with class based views. Instead with viewsets you want to use the [`action` decorator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to mark extra actions for routing:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action


class ChatViewSet(ConversationViewSet):

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get', 'post'])
    def get_chat(self, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `staticmethod` decorator and `request` in `get_chat`:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@staticmethod
def get_chat(request, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Well, I've tried to do that by I'm receiving an outer scope error, idk.

Comment: Just noticed, why is this view inside `ChatViewSet`? I updated my answer. Can you have a try?

Comment: Ofc, idk why I put that method inside of class, thank you!